# The Stack Exchange dropdown menu in the upper left is invisible in Firefox

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, top-bar

[image]It shows up in IE.  It still functions in FF, but it is invisible.

This started a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: I'm running FF 33.0.2 on Win 7 and the dropdown appears fine for me. I'm not sure what version I've got at home on my Win 8 machine, but I know it shows up there too.

Comment: Fine in Chrome on Win8

Comment: I added a screenshot.  The highlighted gray box is where it should be.  It highlights like this when you mouseover.  When not moused-over, it's completely invisible.

Comment: What OS and what version of FF?

Comment: What I've been able to check so far:
FF 33.1 on Win 8.1.  => invisible.  
FF 33.0 on Ubuntu 14.10  => visible.
FF 33.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 => visible.
FF 33.0 on Win 7 => visible.
The FF on Win7 is offering an update to 33.1.1, will do that and report the result.

Comment: This happened to me on all SE sites yesterday, on two different computers. I'm running Pale Moon on Windows 7. But it's back now on all SE sites.

Comment: After updating to FF 33.1.1 on Win 7 it is visible there.

Comment: FF33.1.1 on Windows 8.1 and visible here (fair disclosure: I do use Classic Theme Restorer in FF).

Comment: FF 33.1 on Win 8.1 and it's visible.

Comment: What do you know, it's back.  Thanks to all who replied.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - I was having the same problem at the time. Possible some server maintennance was going on?